# Group by and pivot table with counts

Tags: r, group-by, pivot, summarize

I have a data_frame that looks like this:

```
my_data <- data.frame(
   Datum = c("2022-01-01", "2022-02-02", "2022-03-03","2021-03-09", "2021-02-02", "2020-01-06"),
   Alter = c(45, 33, 22, 34,21, 33),
   Postleitzahl = c("8000", "8001", "8002","8000", "8001", "8002"),
   Triagekategorie = c("red", "yellow", "green","red", "yellow", "green"),
   Nationalitaet = c("Swiss", "German", "Italian","Swiss", "German", "French"),
   Nationalitaet_Typ = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "C"),
   Grund = c("accident", "illness", "injury","injury", "illness", "injury"),
   Typ = c("type1", "type2", "type3","type3", "type6", "type3"),
   Monat = c("01", "02", "03","09", "02", "06"),
   Tag = c("01", "02", "03", "03", "02", "01"),
   Jahr = c("2022", "2022", "2022","2021", "2021", "2020"),
   Ort = c("Zurich", "Geneva", "Basel","Basel", "Geneva", "Bern"),
   Kanton = c("ZH", "GE", "BS","BS", "GE", "BE"),
   geometry = c("POINT(8.54 47.37)", "POINT(6.14 46.21)", "POINT(7.59 47.56)", "POINT(7.59 47.56)", "POINT(6.14 46.21)", "POINT(3.59 44.56)")
 )
```

Now, I need to group this table as in the original, every coordinate occurs several thousand times and needs to be reduced to every coordinate to be unique with all the information still in it. The goal is that for every Zip code I know how many cases there are, the average age. For every distinct entry for each column a new column is pivoted and the count per distinct value per zip-code is counted.

I tried this:

```
# Group by Postleitzahl and calculate statistics
my_data <- my_data %>%
  group_by(Postleitzahl) %>%
  summarise(
    n_cases = n(),
    avg_age = mean(Alter, na.rm = TRUE),
    across(Datum:Nationalitaet_Typ, ~n_distinct(.x, na.rm = TRUE)),
    across(Grund:Typ, ~n_distinct(.x, na.rm = TRUE)),
    across(Monat:Jahr, ~n_distinct(.x, na.rm = TRUE)),
    across(Monat:Grund, ~n_distinct(.x, na.rm = TRUE))
  )
```

But the issue is that the individual levels of each column are not turned into a new column. The goal is that the new data frame would have a column for lets say "Postleitzahl" so there is a column named 8000, on the called 8001 and one 8002 and for each column the count would be 1 and so on for every column entry which is unique.

The data should look something like this (Not all columns are mentioned in the example df):

```r
my_data_expected <- data.frame(
    Postleitzahl = c("8000", "8001", "8002"),
    Average_Age = c(39.5, 27, 27.5), # mean of the age for ZIP
    red = c(2, 0, 0),
    yellow = c(0, 2, 0),
    green = c(0, 0, 2),
    Swiss = c(2, 0, 0),
    German = c(0, 2, 0),
    Italian = c(0, 0, 1),
    French = c(0, 0, 1),
    A = c(2, 0, 0),
    B = c(0, 1, 0),
    C = c(0, 0, 2),
    D = c(0, 1, 0),
    accident = c(1, 0, 0),
    illness = c(0, 2, 0),
    injury = c(1, 0, 2),
    type1 = c(1, 0, 0),
    type2 = c(0, 1, 0),
    type3 = c(1, 0, 2),
    type6 = c(0, 1, 0)
)
```

Comment: The expected df is in the question now, not all variables are listed just to give an idea

Comment: @akrun in the original data frame there are sever entries for each zip, so the Average_Age should be the mean for the "Alter"

Comment: @akrun I have updated the code again

Comment: By comparing the expected and the one I received, it seems to be matching, for type6, it is 0 for my code and you have 1 for the last row.  Is it a typo?

Comment: @akrun No sorry yes your output is correct

Answer (score 0):

This could be a case where we could use `dummy_cols`

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
library(fastDummies)
library(stringr)
cols_nm <- c("Triagekategorie", "Nationalitaet", 
  "Nationalitaet_Typ", "Grund", "Typ")
my_data %>% 
 mutate(avgMean = mean(Alter, na.rm = TRUE), .by = Postleitzahl) %>% 
  select(Postleitzahl, avgMean, all_of(cols_nm)) %>%  
  dummy_cols(cols_nm, remove_selected_columns = TRUE) %>%
  rename_with(~ str_replace(.x, ".*_([^_]+$)", "\\1"), 
  contains("_")) %>% 
 reframe(across(everything(), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)), 
   .by = c(Postleitzahl, avgMean))
```

-output

```
   Postleitzahl avgMean green red yellow French German Italian Swiss A B C D accident illness injury type1 type2 type3 type6
1         8000    39.5     0   2      0      0      0       0     2 2 0 0 0        1       0      1     1     0     1     0
2         8001    27.0     0   0      2      0      2       0     0 0 1 0 1        0       2      0     0     1     0     1
3         8002    27.5     2   0      0      1      0       1     0 0 0 2 0        0       0      2     0     0     2     0
```

-op's expected

```
> my_data_expected
  Postleitzahl Average_Age red yellow green Swiss German Italian French A B C D accident illness injury type1 type2 type3
1         8000        39.5   2      0     0     2      0       0      0 2 0 0 0        1       0      1     1     0     1
2         8001        27.0   0      2     0     0      2       0      0 0 1 0 1        0       2      0     0     1     0
3         8002        27.5   0      0     2     0      0       1      1 0 0 2 0        0       0      2     0     0     2
  type6
1     0
2     1
3     1
```

#### data

```
my_data <- structure(list(Datum = c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", 
"2022-01-04"), Alter = c(45, 33, 22, 24), Postleitzahl = c("8000", 
"8001", "8002", "8002"), Triagekategorie = c("red", "yellow", 
"green", "yellow"), Nationalitaet = c("Swiss", "German", "Italian", 
"Italian"), Nationalitaet_Typ = c("A", "B", "C", "A"), Grund = c("accident", 
"illness", "injury", "illness"), Typ = c("type1", "type2", "type3", 
"type1"), Monat = c("01", "02", "03", "03"), Tag = c("01", "02", 
"03", "01"), Jahr = c("2022", "2022", "2022", "2022"), Ort = c("Zurich", 
"Geneva", "Basel", "Basel"), Kanton = c("ZH", "GE", "BS", "BS"
), geometry = c("POINT(8.54 47.37)", "POINT(6.14 46.21)", "POINT(7.59 47.56)", 
"POINT(7.59 47.56)")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```